# Assigning a class to a custom stage (Puppet)

Tags: rvm, vagrant, puppet

I'm working on my first Puppet file for provisioning a Vagrant setup, and I'm sort of stuck.

I'm using the RVM module to handle Ruby and RubyGem installations, but apparently they use their own custom stage called 'rvm-install' that runs BEFORE the main stage.

In order to get the dependencies for RVM installed (Package resources), I need to run them before the 'rvm-install' stage.  I realized this means I need a custom stage to have run before that.

I've written this class that encompasses the things needing done...but I don't understand how to assign the class to a stage...the documentation at PuppetLabs didn't seem to cover how you're supposed to do it when you already have a block of stuff in the class.

```
class before-rm { 

  exec { "apt-get update":
    command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update"
  }

  package { "libxml2":
    ensure => present,
    require => Exec['apt-get update']
  }

  package { "nodejs":
    ensure => present,
    require => Exec['apt-get update']
  }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.   This is how I've got the Stage defined in the same file:

```
# Custom stage!
stage { 'before-rvm':
  before => Stage['rvm-install']
}

Stage['before-rvm'] -> Stage['rvm-install']
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would instantiate the before-rm class like this for the main stage:

```
include before-rm
```

which is equivalent to

```
class { 'before-rm': }
```

To instantiate a class for another stage you can use the metaparameter (not a parameter of the class, of all classes in general) `stage`.

```
class { 'before-rm': 
  stage => before-rvm
}
```

Here is a link to this in the docs: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_run_stages.html#assigning-classes-to-stages